# Where can I find the JSON Schema for OpenAPI 3.1?

Tags: openapi

I want to automatically check the REST API specification for compliance with the OpenAPI Specification v3.1. But I cannot find JSON Schema for OpenAPI Specification v3.1, only verbal description (https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0). Where can I find the JSON Schema for OpenAPI 3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the official JSON Schemas in the OpenAPI Specification repository:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/tree/main/schemas/v3.1